# Git checkout branch results in merge conflict

Tags: git, merge

On a PHP site, I have two branches, master and feature-branch.

On my localhost I can:

```
git checkout feature-branch
```

look around the site, then:

```
git checkout master
```

and everything works as expected.

On the production server however, switching b/w branches seems to confuse git:

```
git checkout feature-branch
```

look around at the experimental code, but when I then:

```
git checkout master
```

the changes from feature-branch persist. Tried git stash, git pull, same deal.

At that point, I added a comment to a file in master, git push, and git pull on production server, which resulted in a **merge conflict**.

I can fix the merge conflict and move on, but want to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you certain that the files on the production server are not being cached somewhere?  What does `git status` show you after switching back to `master` on the production server?

Comment: Git status doesn't show any modified files. I wondered about caching too, copied everything to a clean VM and got the same issue.

Comment: It sounds to me like the file you are looking at may be the same on both branches in the production server. Have you tried diffing the branches on the production server?
Try `git diff master feature-branch -- file/containing/experimental/changes.php`

Comment: @Alderath Interesting! You're right, the files are identical on production server, but on my local machine they're different.

Comment: Locally and on production, the two branches are up-te-date with remote ?

Comment: Pretty sure they were... now I've made changes to master and fast-forwarded so hard to say for sure w/o backtracking